# Mouse and keyboard not working after stopping xorg process. Persists after reboot

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xorg, mouse

So I accidentally stopped a running Xorg process on my ubuntu (with kill -STOP and the PID). I was trying to stop another process but got the wrong PID.

After I did it, immediately mouse and keyboard stopped working. On reboot, I can log in just fine (mouse an keyboard work perfectly, same goes for my windows setup and also ubuntu in recovery mode), but then the second I'm logged in I can't use mouse or keyboard again (neither usb nor the ones my laptop has). The mouse is just frozen. This means I can't open a command window etc. either.
Other stuff seems to be working normally (time updates in the UI and I get notifications like HPLIP errors).

How can I fix this?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First U Need To Get Access To The Terminal!**

Start Ubuntu like you normally would. Let it get all the way to the login screen. When you get there, don’t sign in. Instead, press `Ctrl + Alt+F3` on your keyboard. Ubuntu will drop out of the graphical login screen and into a black and white terminal.

Enter your username in the prompt, then provide your password when asked. You’ll arrive in a familiar-looking terminal screen. You can navigate here exactly like you do in your graphical terminal windows.

**Then Try The Following Commands :**

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

**Leave A Like, I Hope This Helped You!!..**

Like What I Do Support Me At My Youtube Channel!!! : : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoROPepARvT7Tp4qX2vOyVg/?sub_confirmation=1

Comment: Where am I suppose to try these? I cannot open a terminal much less type anything when I'm logged in... Doing this in recovery mode seems to do nothing.

Comment: Update The Tutorial!!...

Comment: These particular steps didn't work, but the hint on how to get the black and white terminal login really helped. After your suggestion didn't work, I ran "sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all", which I had read on another thread. It didn't work before on recovery root shell, but here it did! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np, Anytime, Need Help, Go To My Yt Channel!!...